# Java: Deleting file from FTP server Error

Tags: java, ftp

I'm reviving a FTP client for some friends and it is basically done but I am having a program deleting files off of it. I have a Button that runs the delete function, it gets the list's selected value, puts it into a string the deletes its, but it is not working. :/

Here is part of my code: (Sorry for any bad conventions)

**JLlist:**

```
public void jlist() {
    //JList, list
    try {
        String[] files = ftpClient.listNames();
        for(String item: files){
            model.addElement(item);
        }
        listScroller = new JScrollPane(list);
        list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        list.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
        list.setVisibleRowCount(3);
        listScroller.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 80));
        listScroller.setBounds(115, 10, 450, 530);      
    }catch(IOException e){}

}
```

**Delete:**

```
public void delete(){

    String deletef = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().toString();
    try{
    ftpClient.deleteFile(deletef);
    System.out.println(deletef);
    boolean deleted = ftpClient.deleteFile(deletef);
    if (deleted) {
        connected.setText("File has been deleted.");
        model.removeElement(deletef);
    }

    }catch(IOException e){
        connected.setText("Something went wrong; try again"); 
    }
```

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `AJAX`, you can't delete with `Java`.

You can use Apache FTPClient to do this and all other commands on FTP. Use it something like this:
    `...
    FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
    client.connect(host, port);
    client.login(loginname, password);
    client.deleteFile(fileNameOnServer);
    client.disconnect();
    ...`

There ya go, not taking credit for that, just found it in a quick search.

Answer (score 0):

first, you are using deleteFile method twice

```
ftpClient.deleteFile(deletef);
System.out.println(deletef);
boolean deleted = ftpClient.deleteFile(deletef);
```

second, are the files being delete (if you check not using other FPT program) ?
meaning to say, is the first deleteFile call working and exception coming from second try ?

Comment: I checked the FTP server and no files are being deleted

Comment: it would be better if you can share the error/exception you are getting